Airflow connection error with Minio bucket
I'm trying to set up an airflow DAG triggered by file uploads to a Minio bucket. However, I'm stuck on configuring the connection in airflow. After providing these information, I ran a test and got this error message:
'EndpointConnectionError' error occurred while testing connection: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://sts.amazonaws.com/"

{
  "aws_access_key_id": "QQsHXqzUTkZlZWAmsML0",
  "aws_secret_access_key": "L8ee1O3Ma4Nr7zriTSTYiaJ6qxF3wyYVnFsNBoWH",
  "endpoint_url": "http://url",
  "region_name": "eu-central-1"
}


To establish a connection with Minio, ensure that the port number is included in the connection details, as outlined in the Minio blog:
{
  "aws_access_key_id": "",
  "aws_secret_access_key": "",
  "endpoint_url": "http://url:port",
  "region_name": ""
}

When utilizing the test connection button in the UI, it invokes the AWS Security Token Service API GetCallerIdentity. This is evident from the error message you encountered. For more details, refer to the Apache Airflow documentation.

If you use the Amazon Provider to communicate with AWS API compatible
services (MinIO, LocalStack, etc.) test connection failure doesn’t
mean that your connection has wrong credentials. Many compatible
services provide only a limited number of AWS API services, and most
of them do not implement the AWS STS GetCallerIdentity method.


this did not solve the issue

can you provide more information, as I use Minio in our local development environment and our connection is imported via yaml.  aws_default:   conn_type: aws   description: "minio (local s3 test environment)"   extra: >     {     "aws_access_key_id": "access_key",     "aws_secret_access_key": "secret_key",     "endpoint_url": "http://local-minio:9000"     }
